# What can I expect from this query using NOT IN?

Tags: mysql

What is the result if you try to run the following query? Assume for this query that all books have a value for publ_id and no publ_id is 90

```
Select *  
From a_bkinfo.books 
Where publ_id not in (90, null);
```

I ran the query and received  no rows, but I thought it this would return rows where the publ_id is  not  90. I am confused. What am I not seeing?

```
Table:
-- create publishers
create table a_bkinfo.publishers (
   publ_id           integer          not null
 , publ_name         varchar(25)      not null  
 , constraint bk_publishers_pk        primary key(publ_id) 
 , constraint publ_id_range check (publ_id >1000)
)engine = INNODB;

Inserts:
-- publishers
Insert into a_bkinfo.publishers values (9000, 'Microsoft Press') ;
Insert into a_bkinfo.publishers values (9456, 'New Directions') ;
Insert into a_bkinfo.publishers values (9102, 'Alfred A. Knopf') ;
Insert into a_bkinfo.publishers values (9325, 'Addison Wesley') ;
Insert into a_bkinfo.publishers values (9745, 'Morgan Kaufmann') ;
Insert into a_bkinfo.publishers values (9521, 'Benjamin/Cummings') ;
Insert into a_bkinfo.publishers values (9822, 'O''Reilly') ; 
Insert into a_bkinfo.publishers values (9030, 'McGraw Hill') ;
Insert into a_bkinfo.publishers values (9444, 'APress') ;
Insert into a_bkinfo.publishers values (9528, 'Manning');
Insert into a_bkinfo.publishers values (9020, 'Princeton Univer Press') ;
Insert into a_bkinfo.publishers values (9021, 'Yale University Press') ;
Insert into a_bkinfo.publishers values (9022, 'Havard University Press') ;
Insert into a_bkinfo.publishers values (9507, 'J.Q. Vanderbildt');
Insert into a_bkinfo.publishers values (9664, 'WROX') ;
Insert into a_bkinfo.publishers values (9825, 'MySQL Press') ;
Insert into a_bkinfo.publishers values (9623, 'Prentice Hall') ;
Insert into a_bkinfo.publishers values (9725, 'Springer') ;
Insert into a_bkinfo.publishers values (9561, 'Houghton Mifflin'); 
Insert into a_bkinfo.publishers values (9902, 'W.W. Norton ') ;
Insert into a_bkinfo.publishers values (9023, 'Holt Paperbacks') ;
Insert into a_bkinfo.publishers values (9024, 'Univ of California Press') ;
Insert into a_bkinfo.publishers values (9776, 'Simon and Schuster') ;
```

Comment: Dont you have the wrong table?Books is not publishers.

Answer (score 1):

It would return a null set.

90 isn't in your values section anywhere....

> Select * From publishers
>   Where publ_id not like '90%';

This would find all the ones that start with 90 and have any combination of numbers after.

By adding the Modulus sign and throwing the single quotes you're looking for a string representation of

`9 0_ _`

**UPDATE**

I'm sorry my initial clause was looking for publ_id WHERE NOT IN ('9038, '9039' for ex.) OTHERWISE you have to use LIKE when you're searching or comparing string of numebrs or letters.

Answer (score 0):

```
Where publ_id not in (90, null);
```

evaluates to publ_id <>90 and publ_id <> null which is unknown or not determined,so you dont get any rows.
If you want rows not having publ_id starting with 90 you can do this

```
Select *  
From publishers
Where publ_id NOT REGEXP '(90)';
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/da75c/10)